# req.user.name is undefined while rendring to template

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am authenticating user using **passport** with **MySql** database in **node.js**. Authentication is done successfully but when  i am rendering **user.name** to home page from **session** then its giving me **undefined**. My code is as below:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("User name " + user.name); //**undefined**
  res.render('home', {
    isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
    user: req.user
  });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("serializing " + user.name);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("Deserializing " + user.name);
    employeeDao.getUserById(user.id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'userID',
      passwordField: 'pwd'
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
      employeeDao.userByUsername(username, function(err,user) {
        if(err)
        {
          return done(err);
        }
        if(!user.length)
        {
          console.log("Not User");
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect user name'});
        }
        if(user[0].password != password)
        {
          console.log("Incorrect Password");
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'});
        }
        return done(null, user[0]);
      });
    }
));

router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect:'/login'}), function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/home');
});
```

My home.ejs page is as below:

```
<% if(!isAuthenticated){%>
    <a href="login">Login here</a>
<%} else {%>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            Hello, <%=user.name%>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%}%>
```

I am not getting what's wrong here.  If passport set user in session then why it's not giving value here.

Comment: I used for this **req.session.passport.user**. Well i don't know it's right approach or not but it worked for me.

Comment: Obviously the **user** is undefined there, you can access the logged in user with **req.user** . serializeUser() and deserializeUser() store the user details in **req.user**